# WPF Datagrid select a value from a cell in a certain row

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with 3 columns(id, User, MachineID) I am looking to get the machine Id from this grid. Preferably I would like to use a check box to select multiple rows, but I just need to get one row at a time sorted.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
          DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserList}" SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCpuID, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding UserID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="User" Binding="{Binding UserName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="210" Header="Machine ID" Binding="{Binding MachineID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

It is bound to the view model but I get the object name instead of the contents of the row(application.Users). I have tried `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCpuID.MachineID, Mode=TwoWay}">` which also did not work. I am quite new to WPF and data binding so I have been trying to work off another program that we have produced here which does a similar thing but uses combo boxes and it doesn't seem to work the same with the datagrid.

Any one know how to get this to work please let me know.
Thanks, 
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably just missing the COLUMNS of the data grid for the display.  The DataGrid's ItemsSource, such as a DataTable, or a Collection (List<>, or other IEnumerable) of all items you want to present to the user.  From there, you need to define each column you want to display and give those characteristics too (width, font, coloring, whatever).  The binding of each column is a path as it would be found on each entry from the UserList.

Then,

```
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}"
    AutoGenerateColumns=False >

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="User" Binding="{Binding Path=User}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Machine" Binding="{Binding Path=MachineID}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now, your UserList source.  If it is such as a List(), then each property should be available via getter/setter, such as...

```
public class SomeUserClass()
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public string User {get; set;}
   public string MachineID {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I do have code similar to that, I should have included it in the post, sorry. What I am trying to do is when the row is selected I want to get the machine ID so I can use it for a query. I will amend my post to show the code for the columns.

Comment: It's OK I have it working now. You got me on the right track I did not realise that my SelectedCpuID property was set to String instead of list(of Users)

Comment: @SamLucas, one final note.  Your "SelectedItem" should be that representing an instance of the same class, so when a user selects a record, that entire object instance will be in your "SelectedCpuID" property.  From there, you can use SelectedCpuId.MachineID (or whatever part of it) for your querying purposes.